# Random walk with absorbing barriers

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk

Consider a random walk with absorbing barriers at $0$ and $3$. $\mathbb P(S_{n+1}-S_n=1)=0.6$ and $\mathbb P(S_{n+1}-S_n=-1)=0.4$. What is the probability of eventual absorption at $0$, given that the starting point is $S_0=1$?

Comment: @JFK Let me know if you have any questions about my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, form the transition matrix corresponding to the random walk with 0 and 3 as absorbing states:
$$P=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\2/5&0&3/5&0\\0&2/5&0&3/5\\0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then, rearrange to have the absorbing states first:
$$\tilde{P}=\left[ \begin{array}{c|c}
  I & 0 \\
  \hline
  S & Q
 \end{array} \right]=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\2/5&0&3/5&0\\0&2/5&0&3/5
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then, compute $M=(I-Q)^{-1},$ and $M\cdot S$. This yields
$$M\cdot S = \begin{bmatrix}10/19&9/19\\4/19&15/19 \end{bmatrix}
$$
These entries are the probabilities of starting at state 1 or 2 and being absorbed at 0 or 3. So, if the chain starts at state 1, for example, the probability of eventual absorption at 0 is 10/19.

FUN with basic linear algebra!

Comment: Can you provide an intuition (or a reference) on why you are multiplying M by S?

Comment: @ThreeDiag - Take a look at Gregory Lawler's book Introduction to Stochastic Processes (2nd ed). Section 1.5, entitled "Transient States", should help. I employed the same notation in my answer that he uses in his book.

Answer (score 1):

Your particular query can be answered very easily by considering a 2D lattice path with each point on X-axis representing a "winning" step (Pr = 0.6), and each step on the Y-axis representing a step towards ruin (Pr = 0.4). If you take a cursory look, you'll see that ruin can only occur after an odd # of steps, and that for each such possibility, there is just *one* way to reach ruin.

So P(get absorbed at 0) = sum of (2/5)^k*(3/5)^(k-1) for k = 1 to oo = 10/19